# How can I share files between Windows PC and a Mac via Ethernet cable?

Tags: mac, ethernet, lan, file-sharing

I have a PC for my intensive workloads and a Macbook Pro for my portable "workstation" and when I need to transfer files between them, I have an Ethernet cable which I can plug into both of them, but as I did, there seems to be no connection at all, even though both devices say my Ethernet cable is connected (with no internet connection). How can I fix this and access files between both the computers?

Comment: If you plug in the cable then you should get a link. But in order to use that you need to 1) Cofigure that link so it can transfer data. 2) Tell at least one OS to share data over it.  For the first part make sure that both get an IP and network mask in the same subnet and that it shows in the routing table. For the second part decide how you want to share. E,g samba share from the windows PC and let the Mac see that. Or NGS, or ....

Comment: Have you considered a software solution, such as Dropbox or Google Drive?  That would avoid having to do the hard connection.  Also, as long as your two computers are on the same network, you can have a folder that is shared on one (that is password protected) and can be accessed on both computers, again without a physical connection.

Comment: What is an "ethernet cable?" I know of no cables that are specific to ethernet. Ethernet runs on a variety of media, and those media can be used for other protocols, too. For example, a UTP cable may be used for ethernet, ARCNET, token ring, TDM, POTS, ATM, etc.

Comment: Have you tried searching [SU]?  I searched for “network computers directly” and found [Transfer files directly between computers over Ethernet cable?](//superuser.com/q/510508/150988), [File transfer between Linux PC and Windows PC through Ethernet cable](//superuser.com/q/1119374/150988), [Connect 2 PCs directly with a cable](//superuser.com/q/594842/150988), [Two Vista machines are connected directly with a network cable](/q/59385/150988), [Direct network cable connection](/q/71922/150988) and [Direct cable connection of two notebooks](/q/367262/150988). Are any of them helpful to you?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You simply cannot connect two machines using an ethernet cable for data transfer. Ethernet cable comes in two different types:

- Conventional: The ones you might use to connect your machine to a router. Machine 1 <---> Router <---> Machine 2
- Crossover: I guess it would be hard to find one. In this cable, the RX, TX cables are crossed-over on the other side. Machine 1 <---> Machine 2

The best bet I guess is to use conventional cables and connect both the machines to a router. Use apps like [Nitroshare](https://nitroshare.net/) to share the files. It supports both Mac and Windows.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

If your Windows PC is configured properly to share connectivity, and you've got both machines connected on your home wireless network, you should be able to see your Windows machine on your network on your Mac without connecting physically with an ethernet cable. If you can, you can transfer files wirelessly.